# dplyr: add rows within group_by groups

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

Is there a better way to add rows within `group_by()` groups than using `bind_rows()`?  Here's an example that's a little clunky:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2), b=1:5)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  do(bind_rows(data.frame(a=.$a[1], b=0), ., data.frame(a=.$a[1], b=10)))
```

The idea is that columns that we're already grouping on could be inferred from the groups.

I was wondering whether something like this could work instead:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  insert(b=0, .at=0) %>%
  insert(b=10)
```

Like `append()`, it could default to inserting after all existing elements, and it could be smart enough to use group values for any columns unspecified.  Maybe use `NA` for non-grouping columns unspecified.

Is there an existing convenient syntax I've missed, or would this be helpful?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(a) %>% do(data.frame(b= c(0, .$b, 10)))` would be one way, if you prefer dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

rbind(df, expand.grid(b = c(0, 10), a = df[ , unique(a)]))[order(a, b)]
```

Depending on your actual context this much simpler alternative would work too:

```
df[ , .(b = c(0, b, 10)), by = a]
```

(and we can simply use `c(0, b, 10)` in `j` if we don't care about keeping the name `b`)

The former has the advantage that it will work even if `df` has more columns -- just have to set `fill = TRUE` for `rbind.data.table`.