# Add a row to a data.frame with conditional mean per each column

Tags: r, aggregate

Imagine I have this dataset:

```
id data_level var1    var2
aa   h         1       4
bb   l         2       5
cc   l         1.4     4.2
dd   h         1.3     3.8
```

I would like to add new rows to get this:

```
id data_level var1    var2
aa   h         1       4
bb   l         2       5
cc   l         1.4     4.2
dd   h         1.3     3.8
h    h         2.3     3.9
l    l         3.4     4.6
All  All       5.7     4.25
```

Where the new row are respectively:

In var 1 the sum for all values with data_level = h, sum for all  values with data_level = l, sum for all values

In var 2 the average for all values with data_level = h, average for all  values with data_level = l, average for all values.

It's basically an aggregation of data conditional on data level. Is there a fancy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very fancy way, but you could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(data_level) %>%
  summarise(id=data_level, var1=sum(var1), var2=mean(var2), .groups="drop") %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  rbind(df, ., c("All", "All", sum(.$var1), mean(.$var2)))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  id    data_level var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
1 aa    h          1     4    
2 bb    l          2     5    
3 cc    l          1.4   4.2  
4 dd    h          1.3   3.8  
5 h     h          2.3   3.9  
6 l     l          3.4   4.6  
7 All   All        5.7   4.25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table::cube()` to calculate sub- and grand-totals..

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("id data_level var1    var2
aa   h         1       4
bb   l         2       5
cc   l         1.4     4.2
dd   h         1.3     3.8")

cube( DT, j = .( var1 = sum(var1), var2 = mean(var2) ), 
      by = c("data_level"), 
      id = FALSE )

#    data_level var1 var2
# 1:          h  2.3 3.90
# 2:          l  3.4 4.60
# 3:       <NA>  5.7 4.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on `dplyr` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551846/dplyr-add-rows-within-group-by-groups)):

```
dts <- read.table(text="
id data_level var1    var2
aa   h         1       4
bb   l         2       5
cc   l         1.4     4.2
dd   h         1.3     3.8
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
dts %>%
 group_by(data_level) %>%
 do(data.frame(var1=c(.$var1, sum(.$var1)),
               var2=c(.$var2, mean(.$var2))
               )
  )


# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   data_level [2]
  data_level  var1  var2
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 h            1     4  
2 h            1.3   3.8
3 h            2.3   3.9
4 l            2     5  
5 l            1.4   4.2
6 l            3.4   4.6
```